# How do I upload my android studio project to github

Tags: android, git, github

I am a newbie on github and am not familiar with it's ins and outs

I know how to locally create a repository on github,but I have no idea about converting my android studio project to a github repository

Screenshot of my project:-[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy8FO.png)

Comment: You might want to look into [this](https://git-scm.com/video/get-going) and [that](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html#ignore-files).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1- create a Github repository

2- open terminal in the project location

3- `git init`

4- `git remote add origin <url of created repository>`

5- `dit add .`

6- `git commit -m 'initial commit'`

7- `git push origin master`

you will see your project in the Github repo you just created.

**Note** You may need to set your credentials for the Github on your local git and create **.gitignore** file.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.I value the help you've given me

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if helped you :)